# Erro a Gerar PDF com PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estou  usando o Phpmailer para realizar envio de email mais gostaria de saber porque quando tento cria um anexo em PDF o arquivo não abre direito,
com o envio esta tudo normal, até o pdf e gerado, só que não abre.
essa função abaixo que estou tentando fazer funcinar.

```
     $mail->addStringAttachment(file_get_contents('teste.php'), 'myfile.pdf');
```

Comment: Fabio, para contornar o problema, crie um .pdf com a classe TCPDF (http://www.tcpdf.org/). Desta forma você primeiro irá gerar o .pdf com TCPDF depois anexar com a classe PHPMailer normalmente como está fazendo.

Comment: to meio perdido aqui pra juntar montar a classe no phpmaille. teria algum exemplo?

Comment: As classes trabalham individualmente conseguiu gerar o PDF com a classe TCPDF? Ficaria mais ou menos assim: `$arquivo = $pdf->Output('arquivo.pdf','S');` depois sim anexaria no PHPMailer: `$mail->addStringAttachment($arquivo, 'myfile.pdf');`

Answer (score 3):

Algumas coisas a entender:

- *PHPMailer* não gera PDFs, ele apenas envia emails
- `file_get_contents` pega o conteúdo dos arquivos e não a resposta da execução de um arquivo, portanto se *teste.php* gera um PDF, ao usar `file_get_contents` o *teste.php* nunca será executado e nunca irá processar o PDF.

Você deve primeiro gerar o PDF e pegar o URL da onde a versão estatica dele é salva ou a variavel aonde os dados dele são salvos, algo como:

O teste.php deve setar o conteudo em uma variavel e enviar usando `return`:

```
...
return $pdf;
```

Então você deve pegar ele assim:

```
$pdfData = require 'teste.php';
$mail->addStringAttachment($pdfData, 'myfile.pdf');
```